# playPause button not resetting upon track skip

Tags: javascript, audio, audio-player

So this was my first time using JavaScript, I have encountered a few bugs with the player. Aside from some CSS issues currently there is only two things not working. Firstly and the main issue for this post is the play / pause button not resetting when I change songs. To play the next song I have to double click, pause back to play and play back to pause (to then start the song) also the auto play nextSong function is not working, which im guessing is related?

The second small issue is the track name not changing. The HTML line for the track you can see is

```
            <div class="song-title">Track1</div>
```

[Visual of player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1to1b.png)

```html
const background = document.querySelector('#background');
const thumbnail = document.querySelector('#thumbnail');
const song = document.querySelector('#song');

const songArtist = document.querySelector('.song-artist');
const songTitle = document.querySelector('.song-title');
const progressBar = document.querySelector('#progress-bar');
let pPause = document.querySelector('#play-pause');

songIndex = 0;
    songs = ['/music/track1.mp3',   '/music/track2.mp3',     '/music/track3.mp3',   '/music/track4.mp3',   '/music/track5.mp3',   '/music/track6.mp3',   '/music/track7.mp3'];
    thumbnails = ['/images/J&G Logo.png', '/images/J&G Logo.png', '/images/J&G Logo.png', '/images/J&G Logo.png', '/images/J&G Logo.png', '/images/J&G Logo.png', '/images/J&G Logo.png', ];
    songArtists = ['Jelly & The GOAT', 'Jelly & The GOAT', 'Jelly & The GOAT', 'Jelly & The GOAT', 'Jelly & The GOAT', 'Jelly & The GOAT', 'Jelly & The GOAT',];
    songTitles = ["Track1", "Track2", "Track3", "Track4", "Track5", "Track6", "Track7"];

let playing = true;
    function playPause()    {
        if (playing)    {
            const song = document.querySelector('#song'),
            thumbnail = document.querySelector('#thumbnail');

            pPause.src = "/images/pause-icon.png"
            thumbnail.style.transform = "scale(1.15)";

            song.play();
            playing = false;
        } else {
            pPause.src = "/images/play-icon.png"
            thumbnail.style.transform = "scale(1)";

            song.pause();
            playing = true;
        }
}

song.addEventListener('ended', function(){
    nextSong();
});

function nextSong() {
    songIndex++;
    if (songIndex === songs.length)  {
        songIndex = 0;
    };
    song.src = songs[songIndex];
    thumbnail.src = thumbnails[songIndex];
    background.src = thumbnails[songIndex];

    songArtist.innerHTML = songArtists[songIndex];
    songTitle.innerHTML = songTitles[songIndex];

    playing = true;
    playPause();
}

function previousSong() {
    songIndex--;
    if (songIndex < 0)  {
        songIndex = songs.length - 1;
    };
    song.src = songs[songIndex];
    thumbnail.src = thumbnails[songIndex];
    background.src = thumbnails[songIndex];

    songArtist.innerHTML = songArtists[songIndex];
    songTitle.innerHTML = songTitles[songIndex];

    playing = true;
    playPause();
}

function updateProgressValue()  {
    progressBar.max = song.duration;
    progressBar.value = song.currentTime;
    document.querySelector('.currentTime').innerHTML = (formatTime(Math.floor(song.currentTime)));
    if (document.querySelector('.durationTime').innerHTML === "NaN:NaN")    {
        document.querySelector('.durationTime').innerHTML = "0:00";
    }   else {
        document.querySelector('.durationTime').innerHTML = (formatTime(Math.floor(song.duration)));
    }
};

function formatTime(seconds)    {
    let min = Math.floor((seconds / 60));
    let sec = Math.floor(seconds - (min * 60));
    if (sec < 10){
        sec = `0${sec}`;
    };
    return `${min}:${sec}`;
};

setInterval (updateProgressValue, 500);

function changeProgressBar()    {
    song.currentTime    =   progressBar.value;
};
```

Please let me know if you need any HTML. Just a note, the icon is switching fine. Thanks for any help, any explainations would be much appreciated :) !

Comment: I would also like to take any constructive critisism on my post, was it formatted the correct way, did I add the right code and in a clear manner? Im new to using this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Discrepancies

<sub>The term ***media tag*** is a generic name for `<audio>` and `<video>` tags.</sub>

- OP lacked any [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) or [on-event properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) so it's safe to assume that there are [on-event attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#HTML_onevent_attributes):

  ```
  <button onclick='lame()' type='button'>Click Me I'm Lame</button>
  ```

  Don't use them, they suck. Instead use:

  ```
  <button type='button'>Click Me</button>

  const btn = document.queryselector('button');

  btn.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);

   /* OR */

  btn.onclick = clickHandler;
  ```
- There's a Boolean called `isPlaying`. Two problems:

  1. It shouldn't be `true` initially. Common sense dictates that `song` is not playing once the page loads (if it does, rethink that for the sake of UX).
  2. Instead of using a flag use the media properties that return a Boolean concerning the status of a media tag (ie `song`): `song.paused`, `song.ended`, and `song.playing`.
- The first `if` conditional of `nextSong()` is wrong:

  ```
  if (songIndex === songs.length)  {...
  ```

  `songs.length` is 7. `somgIndex` range is 0 - 6. So it should be `songs.length -1`
- Didn't include the `<progress>` tag and its handlers, it looks like it's copied correctly...almost. This looks as if it was added on later:

  ```
  setInterval (updateProgressValue, 500);

  function changeProgressBar()    {
    song.currentTime = progressBar.value;
  };
  ```

  `setInterval()` is a poor substitute for the `"timeupdate"` event. A media tag triggers a `"timeupedate"` every 250ms while playing. Use the properties `song.currentTime` and `song.duration` to monitor elapsed time during playback.

  `changeProgressBar()` looks useless. There's already a handler called `updateProgressValue()`. In the only line that `changeProgressBar()` has is a reverse version of one of the lines in `updateProgressValue()`:

  ```
  song.currentTime = progressBar.value;
  progressBar.value = song.currentTime;
  ```

---

### Advice

<sub>The term ***form controls*** is a generic term for `<input>`, `<output>`, `<textarea>`, `<button>`, `<select>`, `<fieldset>`, and `<object>` tags.</sub>
<sub>The term ***ancestor tag*** is a term for a tag that shares the same branch on the DOM tree at a higher level than the ***targets*** -- a term for the descendant tags of the ancestor tags that the developer intends to imbue behavior triggered by an event.</sub>

- If your layout has more than one form control, wrap everything in a `<form>` tag. Doing so allows you to use the [**HTMLFormElement** interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) and [**HTMLFormControlsCollection** API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection). The syntax is terse and simplifies access to form controls.

  ```
   <form id='main'>
     <fieldset name='set'>
       <input>
       <button type='button'>
         [type='button'] is needed when nested within a <form>...
       </button>
       <button>
         ...otherwise it is a [type='submit'] by default.
       </button>
     </fieldset>
     <fieldset name='set'>
       <input id='input1'>
       <input id='input2'>
     </fieldset>
   </form>
   <script>
     /*
     - Referencing the <form> by #ID
     - Or bracket notation document.forms['main'];
     - Or by index document.forms[0];
     */
     const main = document.forms.main;

     /*
     - Once the <form> is referenced -- use the `.elements` property to collect 
       all of its form controls into a **HTMLCollection** (Use an short and easy
       to remember identifier to reference it).
     */

     const ui = main.elements; 
     /*
     - <form> tags and form controls can be referenced by [name] attribute as 
       well. Keep in mind that if there is more than one tag with the same     
       [name] -- then they will be collected into a **HTMLCollection**.
     - Note: There is another fieldset[name=set] -- so in this situation you can
       access them both: `sets[0]` and `sets[1]`
     */
     const sets = ui.set;

     /*
     - To reference a form control without a #ID or [name], its index is always
       available. There's an archaic way as well: `const input = ui.item(1)`
     - There's no need to reference the second <button> because its a 
       [type='submit'] tag. They have default behavior built-in: *Sends data to
       server* and *Resets the <form>*
     */
     const input = ui[1];
     const button = ui[2];

     /*
     - Of the many ways to reference a form control -- #ID is the easiest.
     */
     const i1 = ui.input1;
     const i2 = ui.input2;
  </script>
  ```
- [**Event Delegation**](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) is a programming pattern that leverages [Event Bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) so that we...

  - ...can listen for events triggered on not only an unknown and unlimited number of tags -- we are also able to listen for triggered events for tags that are dynamically created after page load.
  - Moreover, only one ancestor tag that all target tags have in common is needed to listen for events, (`window`, `document`, and `body` are always available, but only use if there is no other tag that's closer to all targets).

    ```
    document.forms[0].onclick = controlPlayer;
    ```
  - The [**Event handler** function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) must pass the [**Event Object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) so that the [`.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property can be used to determine the actual tag that interacted with the user (in this case what was clicked).

    ```
    function controlPlayer(event) {
      const clicked = event.target;
    ...
    ```
  - Once that is established we narrow the possibilities down further. Doing so allows us to exclude tags we don't need to deal with by explicitly excluding them:

    ```
    if (event.target.matches('[type=button]')) {...
    ```
- Changing the appearance of tags to indicate state can be done by toggling `.classes` that have the styles unique to the state it represents. Common practice is to use the [pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after`](https://dev.to/finallynero/understanding-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-ml0)

---

#### Demo

```js
const thumb = document.querySelector('.thumb');
const song = document.querySelector('#song');

const form = document.forms.ui;
const ui = form.elements;
const artist = ui.artist;
const title = ui.title;
const play = ui.playBack;
const prev = ui.prev;
const next = ui.next;

const base = 'https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av';
const songs = ['/mp3/righteous.mp3', '/mp3/jerky.mp3', '/mp3/nosegoblin.mp3', '/mp3/balls.mp3', '/mp3/behave.mp3'];
const thumbs = ['/img/link.gif', '/img/sol.png', '/img/ren.gif', '/img/balls.gif', '/img/austin.gif'];
const artists = ['Samuel L. Jackson', 'Sol Rosenberg', 'Ren', 'Al Pachino', 'Mike Myers'];
const titles = ["Righteous", "Whatnot", "Magic Nose Goblins", "Balls", "Behave"];
let index = 0;
let quantity = songs.length;

const playMP3 = () => {
  play.classList.remove('play');
  play.classList.add('pause');
  song.play();
}

const pauseMP3 = () => {
  play.classList.remove('pause');
  play.classList.add('play');
  song.pause();
}

form.onclick = controlPlayer;

song.onended = function(event) {
  pauseMP3();
  index++;
  if (index > quantity - 1) {
    index = 0;
  }
  song.src = base + songs[index];
  thumb.src = base + thumbs[index];
  artist.value = artists[index];
  title.value = titles[index];
  playMP3();
}

function init() {
  song.src = base + songs[0];
  thumb.src = base + thumbs[0];
  artist.value = artists[0];
  title.value = titles[0];
  song.load();
}

function controlPlayer(event) {
  const clicked = event.target;

  if (clicked.matches('#playBack')) {
    if (song.paused || song.ended) {
      playMP3();
    } else {
      pauseMP3();
    }
  }

  if (clicked.matches('#prev')) {
    pauseMP3();
    index--;
    if (index < 0) {
      index = quantity - 1;
    }
    song.src = base + songs[index];
    thumb.src = base + thumbs[index];
    artist.value = artists[index];
    title.value = titles[index];
    playMP3();
  }

  if (clicked.matches('#next')) {
    pauseMP3();
    index++;
    if (index > quantity - 1) {
      index = 0;
    }
    song.src = base + songs[index];
    thumb.src = base + thumbs[index];
    artist.value = artists[index];
    title.value = titles[index];
    playMP3();
  }
}

init();
```

```css
:root,
body {
  font: 700 small-caps 2.5vw/1.5 Verdana;
}

b {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6ch;
  color: white;
}

output {
  color: gold;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px red;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3vw;
  height: 11.25vw;
  line-height: 11.25vw;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 3rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: lime;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  color: cyan;
}

#playBack.play::before {
  content: '\0025b6';
}

#playBack.pause {
  height: 5.625vw;
  line-height: 5.625vw;
}

#playBack.pause::before {
  content: '\00258e\a0\00258e';
  height: 5.625vw;
  line-height: 5.625vw;
  font-size: 2rem;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#prev::before {
  content: '\0023ee';
  height: 5vw;
  line-height: 5vw;
  font-size: 3.25rem;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#next,
#prev {
  height: 5vw;
  line-height: 5vw;
}

#next::before {
  content: '\0023ed';
  height: 5vw;
  line-height: 5vw;
  font-size: 3.25rem;
  vertical-align: top;
}

figure {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: max-content;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

figcaption label {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.thumb {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.controls {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  height: 6vw;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <form id='ui'>
    <audio id='song'></audio>
    <fieldset>
      <figure>
        <img class='thumb'>
        <figcaption>
          <label>
          <b>Artist:</b> <output id='artist'></output>
        </label>
          <label><br>
          <b>Title:</b> <output id='title'></output>
        </label>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <fieldset class='controls'>
        <button id='prev' type='button'></button>
        <button id='playBack' class='play' type='button'></button>
        <button id='next' type='button'></button>
      </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</main>
```

Comment: The first if conditional of nextSong() is wrong: if (songIndex === songs.length)  {...

This was advice taken from a previous post on the same topic. Its short, feel free to look. It did solve my issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61594245/simple-music-player-for-a-single-7-track-album-javascript-error

Comment: @DecisiveDevelopment you said, *"...also the auto play nextSong function is not working,..."*. What drives `nextSong()` is `index++`  try  `++index` because `if (songIndex === songs.length) {...` is not standard logic... ‍♂️. Moreover, my code works flawlessly and my conditionals are pretty standard.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I've definately reviewed the code and I've decided to re-write it. Thanks :)

Comment: That's gr8, happy coding! 